# Delete all files within a directory vb6

Tags: file-io, vb6, delete-file

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a vb6 function that would delete all files within a directory (excluding subdirectories).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One line, using the VB6 statement [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243388(VS.60).aspx)

```
Kill "c:\doomed_dir\*.*"
```

The [help topic says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243388(VS.60).aspx) "In Microsoft Windows, Kill supports the use of multiple-character (*) and single-character (?) wildcards to specify multiple files".

As an aside - I prefer to avoid the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (including FileSystemObject). In my experience it's occasionally broken on user machines, perhaps because their IT department are paranoid about viruses.

Comment: I always seem to overcomplicate things..I should have remembered this.

Comment: In Access 2000, using the `"*.*"` wildcard with the Kill command will fail if even one file in that directory is locked (or opened).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work:

```
Dim oFs As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim oFile As File

If oFs.FolderExists(FolderSpec) Then
    Set oFolder = oFs.GetFolder(FolderSpec)

    'caution!
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        oFile.Delete True 'setting force to true will delete a read-only file
    Next

    DeleteAllFiles = oFolder.Files.Count = 0
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "User-Defined Type not defined" on "Dim oFs As New FileSystemObject"

Comment: That's because you'll need to add the reference to the FileSystemObject to use it..I don't remember what the exact reference name is though.

Comment: "To use FileSystemObject, you must select the Microsoft Scripting Run-time in the Project References dialog box for your project."

According to:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118

Comment: It's not necessary to iterate the files.  The DeleteFile method of the FileSystemObject will accept wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested every scenario but it should work. It should delete every file and if the file is locked or you don't have access you should get Error 70 which is caught and you get an Abort, Retry or Ignore box.

```
Sub DeleteAllFilesInDir(ByVal pathName As String)
  On Error GoTo errorHandler
  Dim fileName As String
  If Len(pathName) > 0 Then
    If Right(pathName, 1) <> "\" Then pathName = pathName & "\"
  End If
  fileName = Dir(pathName & "*")

  While Len(fileName) > 0
    Kill pathName & fileName
    fileName = Dir()
  Wend

  Exit Sub
errorHandler:
  If Err.Number = 70 Then
    Select Case MsgBox("Could not delete " & fileName & ". Permission denied. File may be open by another user or otherwise locked.", vbAbortRetryIgnore, "Unable to Delete File")
      Case vbAbort:
        Exit Sub
      Case vbIgnore:
        Resume Next
      Case vbRetry:
        Resume
    End Select
  Else
    MsgBox "Error deleting file " & fileName & ".", vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, "Error Deleting File"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 in sympathy because I don't think this deserved -1. Although "Kill " & pathname & "\*.*" is definitely shorter.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the Scripting runtime FileSystemObject's DeleteFile method also supports wildcards as this works for me:

```
Dim fs As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
fs.Deletefile "C:\Temp\*.jpg", true
```

This approach has less control than the approach suggested by @Corazu, but may have some utility in certain cases.