# How to delete all files and folders using vba in Mac?

Tags: vba

I know how to do it in Windows computer. Here is the code for windows:

```
Sub delete_contents_of_Sallima_folder()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim MyPath As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Sallima"

    If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then
        MyPath = Left(MyPath, Len(MyPath) - 1)
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(MyPath) = False Then
        MsgBox MyPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    'Delete files
    FSO.deletefile MyPath & "\*.*", True
    'Delete subfolders
    FSO.deletefolder MyPath & "\*.*", True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

But it is showing error in Mac for this line:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
```

Run time error "429
Active X component can't create object"

How can I do the task in Mac? Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all files within a directory vb6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466766/delete-all-files-within-a-directory-vb6)

Comment: I want to do this for Mac.

Comment: Instead of FSO which is an external reference, use `Dir` and `Kill` which are native to VBA.

Comment: Problem is that RmDir only works for empty folder.